# MongoDB write performance

Tags: php, mongodb, performance, database

Given, **20M documents** with each average of **550bytes** and **PHP driver** on a single machine.

First **insert** (not mongoimport) with `journal on, WriteConcern to default (1)`. Took about **12 hours**. Then it made me wonder, so I tried the second import.

Second, I used **batchInsert()** with `--nojournal and WriteConcern=0` and I took noted the performance. In total **it TOO took 12 hours**?! What was interesting what started to be `40000 records` being inserted per minute it ended up being `2500 records` per minutes and I can only imagine it would have been `100 records` per minute towards the end.

My questions are:

1. I assumed by turning journal off and make w=0 and use batchInsert() my total insertion should drop significantly!
2. How is the significant drop of inserts per minutes is explained?

**--UPDATE--**

Machine is Core Duo 3GHz, with 8GB of RAM. RAM usage stays steady at %50 during whole process. CPU usage however goes high. In PHP I have `ini_set('memory_limit', -1)` to not limit the memory usage.

Comment: Which is collection structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hair pulling, I realized the backlog effect. Interesting enough when I noundled my documents to 5000 rows, batch insert worked like magic and imported in just under **4 minutes**!!

This tool gave me the idea: https://github.com/jsteemann/BulkInsertBenchmark

Answer (score 0):

If it only one time migration, I would suggest you to delete all indexes before these inserts. Using `deleteIndex(..)` method.

After all inserts finished use `isureIndex(..)` to get the indexes back.

PS. From numbers you provided, it is not a big amount of data, probably you have mis-configured the MongoDB Server. Please provide your MongoDB Server config and Memory size, maybe I could find something else to improve.

Replying to your (2) question, probably your server is luck of memory after some inserts.

Comment: I am not adding any secondary indexes, only _id is being created by mongo. Is what you suggest to remove index after each insertion?

Comment: No its ok, if you sure that there is no more indexes, so the only problem I see is MongoDB configuration. I've inserted more than 4GB of data to mongoDB server without any problem. Check the memory limits in your mongoDB config, and how much memory is on your server?